# Jquery push to object only unique elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code like this:

```
var leadNamesForAutocomplete=[];
$('#filterByNameAutosuggestion option').each(function () {
    leadNamesForAutocomplete.push({label: $(this).text(), value: $(this).val()});
});
```

How can i push to leadNamesForAutocomplete only unique label?

Comment: Either push all then de-dupe, or use `filter()` to check for the presence of whatever property value in the array of objects before pushing. Both approaches have been covered on this site if you research.

Answer (score 1):

For unique label, you need to check whether or not the same label has already been pushed.

```
var leadNamesForAutocomplete=[];
var labels = []; // Makes things easier
$('#filterByNameAutosuggestion option').each(function () {
    var label = $(this).text(), value = $(this).val();
    if (!labels.includes(label)) {
      leadNamesForAutocomplete.push({label: label, value: value});
      labels.push(label);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Set` to keep track of labels which have already been stored:

```js
var leadNamesForAutocomplete=[];
var labels = new Set();
$('#filterByNameAutosuggestion option').each(function () {
    var label = $(this).text();

    if (!labels.has(label)) {
        labels.add(label);
        leadNamesForAutocomplete.push({label: label, value: $(this).val()});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.map()` and `.indexOf()` as follows:

```
var leadNamesForAutocomplete=[];
$('#filterByNameAutosuggestion option').each(function () {
    if( loadNamesForAutocomplete.map(o => o.label).indexOf( $(this).text() ) === -1 ) {
        leadNamesForAutocomplete.push({label: $(this).text(), value: $(this).val()});
    }
});
```